# How to color the cell background in Google spreadsheet via Python API

Tags: python, background, google-sheets-api

```py
from pprint import pprint

scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("creds.json", scope)

client = gspread.authorize(creds)

for i in range (1,8):
    sheet = client.open("haniftest").sheet1  # Open the spreadhseet
    cell = sheet.cell(i,1).value
    print(cell)
    sheet2 = client.open("haniftest").worksheet('Sheet2')
    sheet2.update_cell(i,1,cell)
```

I want know how to color the cell background in Google spreadsheet via Python API

Answer (score 1):

For formatting a specific cell, you would need to update the workseet element using format function :

```
worksheet.format('A1:A1', { "backgroundColor": {"red": xx, "green": yy, "blue": zz}
```

You could also look at the gspread-formatting module as well.

Some links :

- Gspread documentation : https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#formatting
- Gspread Formatting module : https://github.com/robin900/gspread-formatting
- Google API doc for formatting : https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#cellformat